# How to change variable value in xsl-loop

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, param

I have an xsl which looks something like:

```
<xsl:param name="relativeURL"/>
<xsl:param name="isPersonalPage" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="main_level" >
        <xsl:with-param name="urlMatched" select="siteMap/siteMapNode/siteMapNode/@url= $relativeURL" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="main_level" match="/">
<div>
<xsl:param name="urlMatched" />
        <xsl:for-each select="siteMap/siteMapNode/siteMapNode">
                <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="(@url = $relativeURL)">
                    <a class="top_link active">
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                            <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="@topNavTitle"/>
                    </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:choose>
                            <xsl:when test="($isPersonalPage = 'true') and (!($urlMatched))">
                                <a class="top_link active">
                                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                                    </xsl:attribute>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@topNavTitle"/>
                                </a>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <a class="top_link">
                                <xsl:attribute name="href">
                                    <xsl:value-of select="@url"/>
                                </xsl:attribute>    
                                <xsl:value-of select="@topNavTitle"/>           
                                </a>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                            </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

So, basically i need to loop through the node and see if the url attribute of any node matches with a specific URL. If so set value of a variable to something else to something else. Then in the called template "main_nav" I wish to do something based on the value of "urlMatched" variable. 
But i am not sure I can alter value of a variable in between or not. Can anyone help me with any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't require a `for-each` due to the way equals tests work when one side is a node set. Simply

```
<xsl:variable name="urlMatched"
    select="siteMap/siteMapNode/siteMapNode/@url = $relativeUrl" />
```

will do what you need, as the expression is true if any of the nodes in the set on the left matches the value on the right, and false otherwise. You should be able to test this value later using `<xsl:if test="$urlMatched">`.

As for using the value in other templates, remember that variables in XSLT are lexically scoped - you will need to pass a parameter if you want to use the value in another template

```
<xsl:template name="something">
  <xsl:param name="urlMatched" />
  <!-- template body here -->
</xsl:template>

...
  <xsl:call-template name="something">
    <xsl:with-param name="urlMatched"
    select="siteMap/siteMapNode/siteMapNode/@url = $relativeUrl" />
  </xsl:call-template>
```

Or just do the calculation in the called template rather than the caller, as `call-template` doesn't change the context so the same select expression will work there too.

Comment: What will my variable contain if it finds or doesn't find the relativeUrl? Cos I need to check the value later and do some coding based on that as well.

Comment: @RossCooper I've added some more info that should help you.

Comment: Hi Ian, I have updated the question with the actual code that I am using now. I am still not getting the required output. Instead I am getting a 500 error. :(

Comment: You were right with the second alternative. I created the variable inside the called template the way you suggested and simply used it. Working perfectly fine. Thanks Ian. :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that variables are read-only in XSLT. That is, you can aasign them only once. After that they are read-only.

See this related question

[update the variable in xslt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673307/update-the-variable-in-xslt/12674683#12674683)

Comment: What is the alternative. I couldn't understand a single thing in the link you gave. I don't think the scenario there is anything similar to mine.

Comment: You cannot update a variable in a loop. You can assign a variable only once. Afterwards is Read-Only. If you try update it you will get a run time error.